# Unknown word: "anned"

Tags: vocabulary

From "*Stranger in a strange Land*", *Robert Heinlein*

> "My passenger must not, repeat, must not be subjected to the strain of a public reception. Provide
> low-gee shuttle, stretcher and ambulance service, and anned guard." ([ref.](https://archive.org/stream/StrangerInAStrangeLandRobertAHeinlein/Stranger%20in%20a%20Strange%20Land%20-%20Robert%20A%20Heinlein_djvu.txt))

What could "anned" mean in this sentence?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on an OCR error in the specific electronic version of the text asked about. It is therefore unlikely to be of significant interest or value to other site visitors.

Comment: Google the first half of the sentence. It’s “armed”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an OCR mistake for "armed guard". (Confirmed by [Google books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Stranger_in_a_Strange_Land/p9UiDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=armed%20guard)).